# TFS build which will copy project files to test server

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I want to create TFS build which after successfully build will copy source files to my server. My project is based on ASP.NET site, then it is not Web Application and I just want to copy files to my remote server.

I am using tfspreview version so I don't have full access to server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the limitations on tfspreview, but usually I would alter the template used in the build and add a CopyDirectory activity to move the directory holding the build solution to another location on the network.

The XAML is stored in source control, and you can create a new one by copying the existing XAML you are referencing and then using the Workflow editor in Visual Studio to add the activity and configure it.

Comment: Is it possible to pass credentials to the CopyDirectory step? This is what I'm trying to get working right now...

Comment: From my recollection, the copy uses the authentication credentials used by the TFS build agent that is executing the build.